# C++ sscanf space delimited string

Tags: c++

Here is my practice code:

```
int integer_part;

char* string_part = (char*)malloc(sizeof(1000));

char* input_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(1000)+sizeof(int));

cin>>input_string;

sscanf(input_string, "%s %d", string_part, &integer_part);

printf("scan: %s %d", string_part, integer_part);
```

I am using this code to take input like `abc 2012` but the result will be `abc 0`

Sadly I didn't see where the problem is. Can anyone help me with this a little? thank you

Comment: `cin >> input_string` will only put `abc` in your `input_string`. Use `getline`.

Comment: `sizeof(1000)` is `sizeof(int)`, typically 4.

Comment: aside from the cin this is not C++, this is c. Don't use malloc/free use new/delete. Don't use printf, use cout, and don't use sscanf use stringstreams and finally don't use char* use std::string

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using char* instead of std:string?

Comment: How about this: `std::string s; int i; std::cin >> s >> i;`? That's about what you're doing now, and you should add error checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads only first space delimited string:

```
cin>>input_string;
```

Use this way:

```
cin>> string_part >> integer_part;
```

Don't mix C++ and C way of reading from streams.

You can use this way to read string without space delimited:

```
cin.read ( input_string, sizeof(1000)+sizeof(int) - 1);
size_t read_Len = cin.gcount();
input_string[read_Len] = '\0';
```

I can understand you need the power of `scanf` to read data in a given format.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `sizeof`. If you want space for 1,000 characters, you don't want the size of 1,000 itself, you want 1,000 times the size of a character. You can use `1000 * sizeof(char)`. Since `sizeof` returns characters (and thus `sizeof(char)` must be 1) you can just use `1000`.